# Hello i want to make a console rpg that favors some enemy spawn over others

Tags: c++

Hello I am trying to Make a console game,
I am trying to make some type of algorithm that favors some enemy spawn over the other,
for example:
I have three enemy units ,those are "Small Troll" , "Big Troll" , "War Troll" , small troll is the weakest and I want him to spawn more then the others while big troll is in the middle and war troll is the last and I want to make him a rare occurrence.
I made a simple algorithm that picks a random element from an array

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    srand(time(0));

    string PickRand[3] = {"Small Troll" , "Big Troll" , "War Troll"};
    int i;

    i = rand() %3;

    cout <<PickRand[i] + " Approaches You!"<<endl;
    if (i == 0){
        cout <<"It has 35 Health"<<endl;

    }else if (i == 1){
        cout <<"It Has 75 Health"<<endl;

    }else if (i == 2){
        cout <<"It Has 200 Health"<<endl;
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dig into `std::discrete_distribution`.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I fixed it myself , here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    srand(time(0));


    int WarTroll[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int WarTrollChance = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<50;i++){
        int WarTrollRandom = rand()%9;
        if (WarTrollRandom == 1){

            WarTrollChance++;
            if (WarTrollChance == 1){

                cout <<"War Troll Approaches You!"<<endl;
            }
        }

    }
```